# Is a bulleted list item always indented exactly 1.8em?

Tags: css, browser, fonts, cross-browser, html-rendering

I made a css-only dropdown menu. The requirement was to have a horizontal bar of items that can each drop down a vertical menu. Furthermore, those items should not drop a tertiary menu, but instead just show bulleted lists. My html has three nested `ul` and the menu is working perfectly in all modern browsers. It looks like this:

[image: original]

However, I did not like how the darker box behind the link is starting right of the bullet and does not stretch over the whole menu width, so I played around a bit and finally came to this tweak:

```
#nav li ul li ul li a {
    padding-left:1.8em;
    margin-left:-1.8em;
}
```

Now the bulleted menu item looks just like I wanted:

[image: working]

And due to the nature of `em` beeing relative to the font size, it works independently of the font size, like shown with a larger font size here:

[image: working (larger font)]

I tested this on Internet Explorer 8+9+10(developer preview), Firefox 3+7, latest Chrome, Opera and Safari and it works like a charm.

However, I just dont understand why it is exactly **1.8em** that does the job. How come every browser indents the bullet items exactly this far? I searched the internet on this topic, but I did not find anything helpful. Can I be sure this works on future browsers? Are those 1.8em specified in the HTML standard?

Thanks in advance for any hint!

**Edit:**

To [DisgruntledGoat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37947/disgruntledgoat) answer: It would not work if I used 1em/-1em or 20px/-20px. With this style:

```
#nav li ul li ul li a {
    padding-left:20px;
    margin-left:-20px;
}
```

I get this (obviously not scaling with the font size) result for different font sizes:

[image: pixel based]

Similarly, 1em/-1em is also off and looks like on the right in the picture above but scaling with the font size. It still looks like 1.8em is the magic distance for some reason...

Comment: Actually the default for all browsers is **40px**, not 1.8em.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: ok, now I'm even more confused... Then why does my solution even work for different font sizes?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't be sure, but my guess would be that it's defined somewhere in your CSS. The bullets, by default, don't actually take up any space, and will be invisible if there is no padding on the list.

Comment: @Ryan Kinal: I set up a Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/24M5q/ if you want to have a closer look. *MenuItem3* is dropping down on hovering.

Comment: Yep. It's defined. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your code, you've set up your `ul` such that it has no margin or padding. However, you've set up your `li`'s such that they have `margin-left: 1.8em`:

```
#nav li ul li ul li {
    display: list-item;
    margin-left:1.8em;
    list-style:disc outside none;
}

#nav li ul li ul li {
    margin-left: 1.8em;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

And there it is.

Comment: omg how could I have overlooked that... Thanks a ton! I feel quite stupid now :)

Answer (score 4):

Based on many years of inconsistent browsers - I'd say you can't trust them to ever be consistent. The best option is to forcibly control it yourself.

You can use that by simultaneously setting the padding-left and margin-left of an `li`. eg:

```
li {
  margin-left: 1.8em;
  padding-left: 0;      
}
```

Apparently some (mainly older) browsers use padding and some margin - so be sure to set both.

Comment: Yes, older browsers (especially IE) did things different, definitely set both.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good point. btw it has to be just the other way round: ``margin-left: 1.8em; padding-left: 0;``. However, that still doesnt explain why every browser today seems to go with 1.8em as a default...

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely do a CSS reset and then set the properties the way you need them. Never trust browsers to be consistent. It adds a bit of coding but at the same time future proofs your code.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my first question (robustness/future proof). I am still wondering where those 1.8em come from and why all browsers use this consistently...

Comment: Resets are counter-productive. Normalization is where it's at.

Comment: But "normalization" is just a more inteligent reset.

Comment: Yeah. You're right. Emphasis on the phrase "more intelligent". The key is to use the *concept* of normalization - style what you're going to use, be aware of the defaults, and don't murder all the styles just to write more. Think [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI).

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question and your comment: your solution works because you negate the padding with the exact same size margin. But the spacing to the left of the list is larger with the larger font size. You would get the same result with 1em padding and -1em margin or 20px and -20px.

As I mentioned in the comment, the actual default padding for lists is 40px. To make things even more confusing, on checking the user agent stylesheets (in Chrome Dev Tool and Firebug for Firefox) they report unique CSS properties: `-webkit-padding-start` or `-moz-padding-start` respectively.

I assume that these special properties are used in place of regular padding due to lists being a special case in HTML - they have hanging bullets/numbers that don't count in the padding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, what you say (in the first paragraph) does not seem to be the case. See my updated.

Comment: @Philip it's because you're applying those values to the `<a>` element not the list. So you're still getting the padding from the `<ul>`.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I kind of mistunderstood you before. I somehow forgot that I assigned a 1.8em margin to the ``li`` \*facepalm\*... Thanks for your help!